# Dynamic information extraaction

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a code for extract information from an .json file and print it on a website. I achived all but now I have a problem, the data is showing only 1 result, it create all boxes/places for the other information but only the first "box" have information.

```
    <head>
    <!-- Title and Extern files -->
    <title>SSL Checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/db.json"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h2>SSL Checker</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="form">
        <p>Introduce the URL:</p>
        <input id="txtbx" type="text">
        <button type="submit" onClick="agregar_caja()">Send</button>
        <div id="inf">
            <p type="text" id="hl1"></p>
            <p type="text" id="hl2"></p>
        </div>
        <script>
            //Extract
            console.log(MyJSON[1].url)
            var cajas = 2
            var boxsaved = MyJSON.length
            fnc = function(info) {
                hey = document.getElementById("hl1").innerHTML = info.url;
            }
            //box creator
            sm = function agregar_caja() {
                document.getElementById("inf").innerHTML += "<p type=text id='hl" + new String(cajas + 1) + "'><br>"
                cajas = cajas + 1
            }
            //Loops
            for (i = 0; i < boxsaved; i++) {
                sm(MyJSON[i]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < MyJSON.length; i++) {
                fnc(MyJSON[i]);
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

And .json file:

```
var MyJSON = [{
    "url": 'google.es',
},
{
    "url": 'yahoo.com',
}]
```

Comment: Please format your JS and JSON code; if you're not sure how to do it yourself, use something like http://jsbeautifier.org. It's hard to read your code, as is.

Comment: Done, can you help me now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your first box is the only element that your `fnc` function alters - notice that it only uses the `hl1` id to access and alter an element, never `hl2+`.

I'll try to keep to your original approach, so that you'll follow it more easily. You might do something like this:

```
var cajas = 2;

function sm(info) {
    cajas = cajas + 1;
    document.getElementById("inf").innerHTML += (
      '<div id="hl' + cajas + '">' + info.url + '</div>'
    );
}

for (var i = 0; i < MyJSON.length; i++) {
    sm(MyJSON[i]);
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks you very much. Can you explain me what you changed? :)

Comment: Basically, your code looped the JSON first to create the elements, and then looped it again to insert a URL in each. My code loops only once and does both steps at once. This eliminates the problem of having to look up the element in the second loop by its generated ID, to insert the URL.

Comment: Ok, thanks you for your help, do you think its possible edit the json file throught the formulary created on the html? Insert one url on the json file when I click "Send"

Comment: How you'd go about doing that will depend entirely on what sort of server you're running.

Comment: I want to do it on local PC, saving the data on the same file .json with the same code

Comment: You'll have to run a local server on your PC and have it serve the HTML and JSON files, and process the form submission. Node.js and Apache+PHP are popular choices for beginners and experts alike.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to read all the code, but as i've got it, you want to add some

elements with url's from your JSON.

Ok, we have parent element div with id='inf', lets use javascript function appendChild to add new elements.

And we will use document.createElement('p') to create new elements.

Here is the code, as I've understood expected behavior.

```
 var infContainer = document.getElementById('inf');
 var elNumber = 2;
 function agregar_caja() {
    MyJSON.forEach(function(item,i) {
        var newElement = document.createElement('p');
        newElement.innerHTML = item.url;
        newElement.id = 'hl'+elNumber;
        elNumber++;
        infContainer.appendChild(newElement);
    }
)}
```

Comment: Your code give me an error, SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.

Comment: It didn't do nothing, don't show nothing and don't create more boxs :/

Comment: I've checked, everything is working fine. This function add's two 'p' elements with urls from your json.

Comment: My guess would be that he didn't *call* the `agregar_caja` function (the code you posted doesn't invoke it). He's learning.